# Use regex in postgres

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression

I want to use regexp_replace() to replace the string

> name1-01.name2-02.1

to

> name1.01-name2.02.1

How to use the regex here?

Comment: Could you please tell which parts are subject to change?  For example, 'name1' is always 'name1' or it can be 'name23' and 'somethingelse543', too?  Additionally, explaining the rules for the change would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace('name1-01.name2-02.1','(.*)-(\d+)\.(.*)-(.*)','\1.\2-\3.\4');
```

Assuming:

- Everything before the first '-' can contain anything but '-'.
- There's always a number after the first '-'
- 'name2' doesn't contain a '-'

Just guessed your requirements, basically. Might be wise for you to read a regular expression tutorial.